# When does kafka-consumer-groups.sh show CURRENT_OFFSET as "-"?

Tags: apache-kafka, partitioning, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

What does it mean that CURRENT-OFFSET column shows "-" ?

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                        HOST            CLIENT-ID
events          6          -               4021552         -               stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer-d6f1 /my.ip  stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          2          -               7056462         -               stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer-d6f1 /my.ip  stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          12         3143580         11052506        7908926         stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer-d6f1 /my.ip  stream-processor-975c-StreamThread-1-consumer
... several other entries, some with and some without "-"
```

What can produce this scenario, and what does it mean for consumers?

I am running a KafkaStreams application over this topic (16 partitions), with 3 instances, one thread each. I had a recent failure of two nodes, and this topic has replication = 2, so some of the partitions remained without leader for some time.

How having partitions in this state affect a regular consumer or a Kafka Streams application?

Comment: How many consumer threads are running?

Comment: Three application instances, one thread each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a consumer did not yet commit its offsets, you will see a dash `-` meaning not available. For the same reason, the lag cannot be computed and shows `-`.

Comment: What are the consequences of "not available"? Is the application not consuming at all from those partitions? How to fix?
This happened after an application stop because of broker failures, but even if the "events" topic had replication=2 (and thus some partitions became leader=-1 in the process), __consumer_offsets had replication=3 and one broker(out of 3) was always available during the process, so they should not be lost, right?
Restarted brokers, then restarted KafkaStreams application, and it has apparently reprocessed from the very beginning (according to the output topic numbers)

Comment: That sound basically correct. What is the retention time for the offsets? If they are not committed for longer than retention time, Kafka deletes them, too.

Comment: That should not be the case - it is a compact topic.  Sent 1Mil more events to process and now no more "-" showing, all 1M processed and lag is now 0. So, what makes it become unavailable? And if they become unavailable, using "earliest", does it mean it will: 1/ start from the beginning? 2/ start from "now"? 3/ continue from where it left off somehow?

Comment: You mean the `__consumer_offsets` topic? Yes, it is compacted, but it still deletes old offset after a retention time (if this would not happen, there would be no mechanism to cleanup the topic for consumer groups that are not used any longer, because you cannot write tombstones manually). Compare https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-186%3A+Increase+offsets+retention+default+to+7+days -- if you specify reset policy "earliest" is will process from the beginning. If you specify "latest" it start from "current end of log".

Comment: Sorry, I was replying about my actual topic's retention, not "offsets.retention.minutes". I understand now, thanks.